# Android Studio - how to install Android platform tools on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit?

Tags: android-studio, 64-bit, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install Android Studio on a 64 bit version of Ubuntu 14.04. However my installation stops at this point:

[image]

How can this be resolved ? Any suggestions or a solution itself would be most appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

Edit: 
Am I on the right track when I assume that this has something to do with the lack of 32 bit binaries on a 64 bit version of Ubuntu ? I tried logging in as root repeated the installation process, however the issue still persists. What am I doing wrong ? Is there an alternative way of installing platform tools ? Also, this is what my terminal tells me:

```
[  26263]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - platform-tools, tools and 7 more SDK components were not installed 
com.android.tools.idea.welcome.WizardException: platform-tools, tools and 7 more SDK components were not installed
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.promptToRetry(InstallOperation.java:109)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsOperation.perform(InstallComponentsOperation.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsOperation.perform(InstallComponentsOperation.java:38)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation$1.compute(InstallOperation.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallContext$Wrapper.run(InstallContext.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.ProgressStep.run(ProgressStep.java:167)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallContext.run(InstallContext.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.runLongOperation(InstallComponentsPath.java:301)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.doLongRunningOperation(FirstRunWizard.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.access$000(FirstRunWizard.java:41)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1.run(FirstRunWizard.java:160)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost$LongRunningOperationWrapper.run(FirstRunWizardHost.java:432)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
[  26271]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - Android Studio 1.1.0  Build #AI-135.1740770 
[  26277]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - JDK: 1.7.0_75 
[  26277]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[  26277]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[  26277]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - OS: Linux 
[  26277]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - Last Action:  
[  31892]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Watcher terminated with exit code 0
```

Comment: Have you downloaded android sdk?

Comment: I used this link to download Android Studio http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html ( specifically the last link at the bottom of the page under the section All Android Studio Packages) and the SDK tools are bundled along with the package. What am I doing wrong ? I know I can manually download and install SDK tools but what needs to be done for the installer to do this for me ?

Comment: What you downloaded is just Android-Studio IDE. You need to download [stand alone SDK tools](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) once downloaded extract it and then set sdk path to android studio

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, answering my question. I still really don't know why Android Studio's installer does not complete the installation for me, but one workaround is to manually download all the components you need (or rather the components that Android Studio cannot install) by going to:

```
/home/<your-system-name>/Android/Sdk/tools
```

and then running the Android shell script file.

Use

```
sh Android
```

and download all the components you need from the SDK manager. Once you are done run the studio.sh script file from:

```
/home/<your-system-name>/Documents/android-studio/bin/
```

or from where you have Android Studio extracted.

Note that Android Studio may still tell you that certain other components cannot be installed and all you have to do is to repeat the process i.e manually download the components that Android Studio needs and then run studio.sh.

Also ensure that you have a 64 bit version of Oracle Java and the necessary 32 bit executables(as @Archer Riley's answer indicates) to complete installation.

Answer (score 13):

It's because Android Studio needs 32 bit libraries, and in your 64 bit version linux, it doesn't have. You can install the 32 bit version libs by typing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

and then retry what you were doing.

Comment: and if you got an aapt problem, please install "sudo apt-get install lib32z1"

Comment: when I run this commads I get `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 2):

For recent Ubuntu versions, the official documentation recommends this libs:

$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1

(On older versions of Ubuntu the command to run was sudo apt-get install ia32-libs).

Source: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/linux-32-bit-libraries

Answer (score 1):

Before running ./studio.sh, I had to install a few 32-bit libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5
sudo apt-get install lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Once those are installed, I was able to complete the installation without the `mksdcard` error.